# websites resolving in browser but not resolving in CLI. Can ping IP but not domain name (unknown host)

Tags: ubuntu, dns, home-networking, ping, ruby-on-rails

Hi guys I'm currently developing using rails and for some reason bundle install is returning the following output

```
Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
Fetching full source index from https://rubygems.org/
Could not reach https://rubygems.org/
```

I've discovered that pinging by domain name keeps returning an unknown host.

The browser is still resolving web pages just fine and I've managed to confirm that the problem is localized (i.e. the rubygems page isn't down). I'm completely lost so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the browser and cli on the same machine, and are you running a proxy server?

Comment: @Paul They're running on the same machine

Comment: if you ping another host does it work?

Comment: Does the web browser have a proxy configured?

Comment: @grawity the web browser doesn't have a proxy configured

Comment: @devius I can ping 8.8.8.8 and that seems to work fine, I've also tried pinging rubygems.org and whilst it's a lot slower it doesn't seem to end in packet loss.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your DNS configuration. Take a look in the /etc/resolv.conf file and the files under /etc/resolvconf/ and see if there's something fishy going on there. In theory the IPs you see there should match your network settings in the GUI. Also, try configuring your network connection with a static IP if you haven't done so already.

Comment: For some reason the problem wouldn't go away when I rebooted the computer but logging in and out fixed it. Might just be coincidence but happy enough with that. I noticed that the problem kept happening after I'd come home from university (where I do use a proxy). I'd been triple checking that the proxy was turned off but I'm guessing Ubuntu kept the proxy on the terminal for some reason. Logging in and out seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

When you ping, you shouldn't add a slash after the domain. Thus:

Incorrect:

```
ping rubygems.org/
```

Correct:

```
ping rubygems.org
```